# Flask table and LinkCol, ButtonCol - passing value as URL parameter instead of path to endpoint possible?

Tags: python, url, flask, url-routing, flask-table

I have a function defined as follows:

```
@app.route('/products', methods=['GET'])
@app.route('/products/<id>', methods=['GET', 'PUT'])
def foo():

  id = request.args.get('id', type=int)
  if id != None and request.method in ['GET', 'PUT']:
    # route to editing product template
  else:
    # display products as table
```

I have defined a Flask table like this:

```
class ProductsTable(Table):
  id=Col('ID', show=False)
  price=Col('Price')
  available_online=Col('Available online?')
  available_num=Col('In stock')
  edit=ButtonCol('Edit', url_kwargs=dict(id='id'), endpoint='/products')
```

I query an SQLite DB and fill the table. Displaying it works fine however I am struggling with the editing functionality.

Right now the way it works once the user presses the Edit button the URL changes to `http://localhost:5000/products/1`, `http://localhost:5000/products/2` etc. depending on the ID of the item in the DB and respectively in the table (since it just displays the DB data).

However I would like to find out if it's possible to pass the ID as an URL parameter so that the URL for editing a specific product by pressing the Edit button becomes `http://localhost:5000/products?id=1` `http://localhost:5000/products?id=2` etc.

I tried passing `'/products/<id>'` to the `endpoint` argument but I get the following error

> **werkzeug.routing.BuildError:** Could not build url for endpoint `'/products/<id>'` with values `['id']`. Did you mean `'products'` instead?

I also tried `'/products?<id>'`, `'/products?id=<id>'` and also without the `/` in front of `products` but the result was the same. The only valid endpoint here is just `products`.

Is this possible and if yes, how can I achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

I use the following format:

```
edit = LinkCol('Edit', 'app.foo', url_kwargs=dict(id='id'))
```

Equivalent to `url_for('app.foo', id=id)`